# Capture request & response from charles proxy using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, charles-proxy

I am trying to automate a Video stream player application something like netflix.
What i do now:
I have to tune to a couple of programs / channels manually and check the response in charles proxy to verify if the streaming comes from the right source and validate bitrate, response time and manifest information etc.

What i need to do:
I want to automate the above process. I have searched in the web where people have mentioned about getting the responses for certain browsers ( Firefox / chrome). We can get the responses from firefox using the web console i guess.

I want to write an automation script that is generic enough, so that i can run the tests on different web browsers and compare the responses to one source i.e charles proxy.

Below is what i am thinking of.

cucumber (my test cases) + selenium Web driver (automate things) + Charles proxy ( to validate responses)

Kindly help me if anyone has done this before. Sort of interesting and challenging. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Were you able to figure it out.I need help in doing it